# How can I get the ImageNet ILSVRC 2012 data used for the classification challenge?

Tags: imagenet, image-classification

I want to download the ImageNet dataset for classification. Currently, the link in all of the deep learning frameworks (Tensorflow, Pytorch) has been removed. I have registered in image-net.org, but unfortunately, I have not received any news from them in almost a month. the support email is not valid. How can I download this dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register with edu email? If not, the download request will probably be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

According to the website, only official email addresses like college or company will work. You'll need one of those email IDs